# Can uncountable be defined as unable to be generated by any algorithm

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to describe the concept of uncountable to someone with even less knowledge of math than myself ;-). I came up with the idea that for any countable set, $S$, you could create an algorithm $A$, such that for any proper subset $T$ of $S$, you could generate all elements of $T$ <strike>in a finite number</strike> with a sufficient number of iterations of $A$, but that for an uncountable set, there is no such algorithm that could do this for every proper subset.

Is this a valid statement?

Comment: No, not every subset of a countable set can be generated by an algorithm.

Comment: What if you take an infinite proper subset $T \subset \{s_1, s_2, s_3, ...\}$?  How do you generate an infinite number of elements in finite time?  On the other hand, for any finite subset $T$ you can just list the elements of $S$ and stop once all elements of $T$ have appeared.

Comment: You're close.  The real setup is as follows.  For any countable set, there is an algorithm that eventually lists every element.  For finite sets this is easy.  For infinite sets this algorithm will never finish, but still, for any given item in the set, the algorithm will get to it eventually.  For an uncountable set, there is no algorithm that gets to everything eventually, EVEN IF YOU WAIT FOREVER.  For example, there is an algorithm that eventually lists all the rational numbers, but no algorithm that eventually lists all the real numbers.

Comment: What is an algorithm? What does it even mean for an arbitrary set to be generated by an algorithm?

Comment: @MarkVY How do you list the countable set of all Turing machines that do not halt on the empty string?

Comment: Okay, my bad.  If there is no algorithm to reliably distinguish "something in my set" from "something not in my set", then of course there's no algorithm to list everything in the set.

Comment: @MarkVY Your comments here are wrong in a number of ways. Your first comment asserts that every countable set is recursively enumerable (we can write an algorithm to list the elements), which is false. It also says that there is no algorithm that lists all the real numbers, but it's not even clear what it means to "list" even a single real number that's, e.g., transcendental. Your second comment says that any set which is not recursive cannot be recursively enumerable, but this is also false.

Comment: Wait, really?  Is there an easy example of a set such that we can list its elements but can't tell if something belongs to the set?  This sounds like it can't be true, since we can simply consult the list to see if the proposed element is on it.  I admit I'm a bit out of my depth here (seriously, recursive wha??), but I thought I knew at least this much.

Comment: @MarkVY [The halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) $H$ is a good example of this: we can enumerate it (put $e$ into $H$ when we see the $e$th Turing machine halt on input $e$), but we can't co-enumerate it (how do you know the $e$th Turing machine on input $e$ will *never* halt? no matter how long you wait, maybe it halts in "just one more step").

Comment: Oh, that's nice!  I never thought about that.  So although you can't enumerate the set of all machines that loop forever when given the empty string, it's actually easy to enumerate the ones that halt!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No.

There are uncountably many subsets of $\Bbb N$ (and all these subsets are countable). But there are only countably many algorithms. Hence you cannot describe all these sets by an algorithm.

On the other hand, there are real numbers that cannot be described by an algorithm (again, because there are more real numbers than algorithms). For such a number  $\alpha$, already the singleton set $\{\alpha\}$ is problematic for your approach.

Comment: Can you point to a resource regarding this definition of algorithm? I come from CS background and I think the definition in my head is too flimsy for this to make sense. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't really matter how you define an algorithm. There are only countably many *strings in the English language*; as long as each string in the English language defines at most countably many algorithms, and each algorithm is described by some English string, there are only countably many algorithms.

Comment: Here, presumably "algorithm" is being used in the sense of computability. Almost all definitions turn out to be equivalent (Turing Machines, register machines etc). This equivalence is known as Church's Thesis. It's not and can't be a theorem, but in practical terms this seems to be how it is.

Comment: @ReedSpool The conventional definition in CS is that "algorithm" means "Turing machine".

Comment: Ok, I'm mindblown that there are an uncountable number of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$! But I'm not sure you totally got my question: I'm _not_ looking to enumerate all the subsets of a countable set, I'm talking about enumerating _any given subset_, unless I'm missing some kind of equivalence between these two tasks. Also note that I've updated my question to remove the limitation of a finite number of steps, though I don't think that's specifically relevant to your answer.

Comment: @brianmearns Since there are uncountably many subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and only countably many computer programs, "most" subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ don't have corresponding computer programs.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Thanks, that makes it very clear =)